# Javascript changing style display from none to normal does not work

Tags: javascript, html

This is my imgage:

```
<img alt="" id="loadingImage" src="Images/ajax-loader.gif" style="display:none"/>
```

I want to show the image with a javascript, this is my code and it does not work:

```
function changeDisplay() {
    var img = document.getElementById('loadingImage');
    img.style.display = "normal";
}
```

HOWEVER

If i do the "inverse", going from normal to hidden it works just fine with this code:

```
<img alt="" id="loadingImage" src="Images/ajax-loader.gif" style="display:normal"/>

function changeDisplay() {
    var img = document.getElementById('loadingImage');
    img.style.display = "none";
}
```

I dont get this, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please check available [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) values.

Comment: `img.style.display = ""`

Comment: there is no display:"normal". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, as you can deduce for the answers and comments received, there is no `normal` display.

Now, if when you say `normal` you mean to go back to the default `img` display mode, then you should go for `display: inline`. Almost all the answers assumed that `block` was the normal one. But `img` is one of the [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente), not a [block element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements).

```
function changeDisplay() {
    var img = document.getElementById('loadingImage');
    img.style.display = "inline";
}
```

However, if when you say `normal` you mean going back to the previous display mode it had before, the one calculated applying any CSS rule, then I would go for the solution proposed by @ArunPJohny [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927792/javascript-changing-style-display-from-none-to-normal-does-not-work#comment-42401536). Just *remove* the display mode.

```
function changeDisplay() {
    var img = document.getElementById('loadingImage');
    img.style.display = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `display:normal`, but here is one example:

```js
    function show() {
        var img = document.getElementById('loadingImage');
        img.style.display = "inline";
    }
    
    function hide() {
        var img = document.getElementById('loadingImage');
        img.style.display = "none";
    }
```

```html
<img alt="" id="loadingImage" 
src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Wikipedia-logo-v2-pt.png" style=""/>

<a href="#" onclick="window.show()">show</a>
<a href="#" onclick="window.hide()">hide</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

style not have display:normal;
Have's
display:none; Not show
display:block; Show

replace
    img.style.display = "normal";
on This
    img.style.display = "block";

```
function changeDisplay() {
    var img = document.getElementById('loadingImage');
    img.style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use display "block"

`img.style.display = "block";`

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 1):

use below style

```
img.style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
function changeDisplay() {
    var img = document.getElementById('loadingImage');
    img.style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> u can use this function

```
function show() {    
  var contentId =
     document.getElementById("loadingImage");   // Toggle   
     contentId.style.display == "block" ? contentId.style.display = "none"
    :  contentId.style.display = "block";  }


<img alt="" id="loadingImage" 
    src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Wikipedia-logo-v2-pt.png" style=""/>

<a href="#" onclick="window.show()">toggle</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is no "normal" property value for display,but you can ues "block",to show the pic up.you can find more details form [w3shools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)